# $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); // ImagesController Controller class could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Good morning guys.
In **error_log** *CakePHP* is accusing the following:

```
28/11/2011 10:13:27 Error: [MissingControllerException] ImagesController Controller class could not be found.
# 0 /........./app/webroot/index.php (96): Dispatcher-> dispatch (Object (CakeRequest), Object (CakeResponse))
# 1 {main}
```

I haven't idea what it is, because I **haven't** *ImagesController* but have **ImagesComponent**.

**Code snippet:**

```
// app/Controller/BrandsController.php    
class BrandsController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Image');
...

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

            if(!$this->request->data['Image']['name1']['error']) {
                $this->Brand->create();

                $image_path = $this->Image->uploadImage(
                    $this->request->data['Image'], 
                    'Brands',
                    array(
                        'folder'=>'upload/imagens/marcas',
                        'resize'=>175,
                        'thumb'=>0,
                        'original'=>false,
                        'name'=>$this->request->data['Brand']['brand']
                    )
                ); 

// app/Controller/Component/ImageComponent.php
class ImageComponent extends Component {

public $components = array('String');

function uploadImage($images, $controller, $data) {
    $erroimg = false;
    $isfile = false;
    ...
```

What is the cause of this error?
**Sorry for my english**

Comment: not sure if relevant - from the docs: `When you don’t have a [Plugin]AppController and [Plugin]AppModel, you’ll get missing Controller errors when trying to access a plugin controller.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log shows a stack trace with the methods leading to the error. In your case [`Dispatcher::dispatch`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L54) was called. The docs of this method read:

> Dispatches and invokes given Request, handing over control to the involved controller. If the controller is set to autoRender, via `Controller::$autoRender`, then Dispatcher will render the view. Actions in CakePHP can be any public method on a controller, that is not declared in Controller. If you want controller methods to be public and inaccessible by URL, then prefix them with a `_`. For example `public function`_loadPosts() { }` would not be accessible via URL. Private and protected methods are also not accessible via URL.
>
> If no controller of given name can be found, `invoke()` will throw an exception.
>   If the controller is found, and the action is not found an exception will be thrown.

Internally, dispatch will call [`Dispatcher::parseParams`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L126) to parse the Request to determine the controller to call. If any routes have been configured, `parseParams` will apply them

> Applies Routing and additionalParameters to the request to be dispatched.
>   If Routes have not been loaded they will be loaded, and app/Config/routes.php will be run.

In other words: you requested a URL that the Dispatcher wants to pass on to the Image controller. You don't have an ImageController and that's why you get the error. So, add an ImageController or change how CakePHP routes.

Comment: Yes, but, see: this a URL: http://example.../brands/add. In my app/Config/routes.php have just a default routes. So, I not understand. Nowhere I call the Image Controller.

Comment: I found a solution: I use virtual hosts in my local server, and when I try upload big files (up to 2mb), CakePHP return error. Now I added in <VirtualHost ....:80> php_value upload_max_filesize 30M, and other values, e is working properly.

Comment: @Patrick Another option would be to install a debugger and step through the code to see what happens. This will lead you to the error.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a broken image path somewhere in your CSS or HTML output (ie. `<img src="images/doesnotexist.jpg"`). CakePHP's default rewrite rules (in `webroot/.htaccess`) will try to dispatch requests (through `webroot/index.php`) if they do not exist as static files on the filesystem under the `webroot/` directory. Cake is throwing an error instead of a 404 as you are in debug mode.

Comment: @deizel I don't know, but I think the problem is only with Virtual Host. Anyway, I will return the 001-default file the original version and do some testing.

Comment: @deize It was really a bug in css (directory invalid image), the front-end forgot to change. After correction, the errors stopped. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you found it. :)